# Python Selenium, is there a way to click a radio button? My code doesn't work on the site

Tags: python, selenium, radio-button

```
driver.get('https://search.naver.com/search.naver?where=nexearch&sm=top_hty&fbm=1&ie=utf8&query=%ED%99%98%EC%9C%A8')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="_cs_foreigninfo"]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/ul/li[2]/div/a/span').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below xpath :

```
//div[@class='radio_check _radioBtn ']//a
```

**Code 1 :**

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='radio_check _radioBtn ']//a").click()
```

**Code 2 :**

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='radio_check _radioBtn ']//a"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, but this source is not clickable.

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='radio_check _radioBtn ']//a").click()

Comment: What was the exception ?

Comment: don't know the meaning. Here's the full code: 

from selenium import webdriver import time driver = 

webdriver.Chrome('E:/CODE/chromedriver.exe') driver.get('search.naver.com/…) 
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='radio_check _radioBtn ']//a").click() 

time.sleep(5) 
driver.close()

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code.

```
driver.get("https://search.naver.com/search.naver?where=nexearch&sm=top_hty&fbm=1&ie=utf8&query=%ED%99%98%EC%9C%A8")
buttons = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("ico_radio")
for i in range(len(buttons)):
    buttons[i].click()
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Your code works very well. I will often come to learn skills. ^^